# Google service connection + Corp wifi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-nexus-s, data-connection, proxy

When connected to the corporate wifi the signal bars turn grey suggesting that there is no connection to Google services. Gmail, web browsing, contact sync, calender sync, play music all appear to work correctly. YouTube and DeskSMS do not, there may be others but I haven't been specifically looking for what does and doesn't work. Both services accessed via computer work perfectly fine, there is no block on YouTube or DeskSMS. I'm running Android 4.1.2 on a Nexus S, DHCP network configuration with HTTP proxy.

Any suggestions as to why the phone believes it doesn't have Google service connectivity?
Broken YouTube doesn't bother me but DeskSMS would be handy to get working, any suggestions?

Comment: I bet you can't sing in to Google Talk.

Comment: Correct, that's not working either.

Comment: When it can't connect to Google Talk it believes that there is no service.

Comment: So is there a protocol/url/port that needs unblocking? How would I find out?

Comment: Check http://thoughtpad.cs3.in/2007/03/07/blocking-google-talk-in-your-organization/